# How to test for array object presence with bash variable using yq

Tags: arrays, yaml, yq

Given the file `test.yaml`:

```
[alpha, bravo, charlie, delta]
```

and the variable:

```
echo $WORD
# bravo
```

How do we test whether `test.yaml` contains `$WORD`?

I have tried `yq 'contains(["$WORD"])' test.yaml`, but this yields `false`.

I am using Mike Farah's yq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [pmf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2158479/pmf)'s guidance, the solution is to:

```
WORD="$WORD" yq 'contains([strenv(WORD)])' test.yaml
# true
```

Source: https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/env-variable-operators#read-string-environment-variable

Comment: yq doesn't need double quotes. You needed them to inject data into code, which is a bad practice. yq provides access to environment variables through `env`. Try `WORD="$WORD" yq 'contains([env(WORD)])' test.yaml`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).